# Why Can't Ubuntu Server 16.04 Update After Install

Tags: 16.04, server, updates

I am brand new to Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server. My aim is to set up a Plex media server using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. Ubuntu has been successfully installed on my system which has a hard wired internet connection but I keep getting errors and "Failed to fetch..." prompts after executing command "sudo apt-get update". Even after restarting the system and/or powering off and restarting, the issue remains.

I also tried to ping Google.com using "ping -c3 www.google.com" but I get the response "unknown host www.google.com" so not sure if there might be a network issue (see attached image for errors and other issues mentioned).

[Image showing command line errors][1]

I've done quite a bit of scouring but can't seem to find a solution. I am also new to the CLI, so any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I had initially set up my server with a static IP but was getting no internet connection. As per instruction from @Joel to get a new IP address from my router, a new IP was obtained by updating the Network Interfaces file using the VI Editor (command: sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces) and changing the primary network interface back to 'dhcp' from 'static' (iface enp3s0 inet dhcp).

After rebooting I was successfully able to ping 8.8.8.8 (Google) and thus perform updates.

Big thanks to @joel and @f35 for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can try changing the DNS-server your server is using. To do that type in the following command:

`nano /etc/network/interfaces`

and add the following line (or change it if it's already there) :

`dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

Now your server should use the Google dns server (but of cause you can use any other dns server you want)*

**EDIT:**
Now that you have shown the result of `ping 8.8.8.8` its looks like your pc is not connected to the internet. You can try to get a new ip-adress from your router by typing `sudo dhclient -r eth0` If this still does not work you can try assigning you pc a static ip-adress.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Joel. Using "nano" comes back with "invalid command". After previously watching a video online I've been replacing "nano" with "vi" which brings up the vi editor I believe it's called. That way I've been able to change the info in the interfaces file. I've changed the DNS-server as instructed but I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: try restarting the server after changing the dns server

Comment: Yep, did that, typed the update command, same result.

Comment: ok, I forgot to mention that you will have to add that line below the interface you are using. If you are wired it should be 'eth0' and will look something like "iface eth0 inet static"

Comment: I wish I could send an image of the results I get but it seems I can't do so when replying to your comments. I mentioned the same to @f35. In addition  instead of showing 'eth0' I get 'enp3s0'. From what I've read this is a new thing in Ubuntu Server 16.04.1

Comment: just add the information to your question

Comment: I actually have already set up a static IP using the VI Editor:  'vi /etc/network/interfaces and changed 'DHCP' to 'Static'. If possible, Joel, since every time a comment is left I'm being prompted to 'move this discussion to chat' I'm going to start a chat a bit later if that's fine with you.

Answer (score 0):

Is `ping 8.8.8.8` working ?

If no, it means you have a network configuration problem.

Show us the result of

- `ifconfig -a`
- `netstat -rn`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response also, f35. I wish I knew how to copy and paste the results of the commands you gave, would make replying a whole lot easier! Forgive me. And if I add an image to my response it just shows the location of the image on my computer in text format

Comment: That said, the ping result for 8.8.8.8 came up 'Desitnation Host Unreachable'.

Comment: Ping 8.8.8.8 is not working. "Destination Host Unreachable". See image in updated question for 'ifconfig -a' and 'netstat -rn'

Comment: Your default gateway is 192.168.1.254, are you able to ping it ? ping 192.168.1.254, is it correctly configured ? Does it provides a correct dhcp ?

Comment: Pinged the gateway, again 'Destination Host Unreachable'. I've set up my Ubuntu machine with a static IP using the VI editor and used the IP address provided from 'ifconfig'

Comment: I can access my gateway online user interface via my Mac computer with no problems when connected with the same ethernet cable. I have no issues connecting to the net with any other devices, whether hard wired or over wifi. Issue is only with my Ubuntu machine. Hope the clears up a few things.